# Conversion from XML to Json removes 0 in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am converting XML files to Json(gzip compression) using Azure Data Factory.

However , I observe that in the XML file I have the values stored as 0123456789. However , when this is converted to Json it is saved as "value" : 123456789. Without 0.

I would like to keep the Json values as-is from the XML . Please provide suggestions for the same.

Comment: Can you add a pair of single quotes to the value?  0123456789-> '0123456789'.

Comment: I have an incoming XML which I dont have control to modify it.

Comment: Any workaround to overcome this ?

Comment: Are you using data flows or copy? If you are using data flows, you can transform the property from number to string and add the leading 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found using data flow will solve the problem.

1. I created a simple test. My xml file is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
<to>George</to>
<from>John</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget the meeting!</body>
<number>0123456789</number>
</note>
```

2. Set the xml file as the source data. Please don't import `Projection`.
   By default, all columns will be treated as string types.
   [image]
   The data preview is as follows:
   [image]
3. Set the json file as the sink:
   [image]
4. Select `Output to single file` and specify the file name.
   [image]
5. The debug result is as follows:
   [image]

That's all.

Comment: Hi@amit agarwal, Please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Comment: Thanks this helps. Also I found another way of doing it.

Comment: Hi @amit agarwal. Could you please share your solution or accept(mark) my solution as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Very thanks!

Comment: I have accepted your solution as answer , however due to my reputation it is not reflected.

Comment: You can click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: The solution what I tried was to disable Detect Data Type flag.

Comment: @amitagarwal I have the same problem using copy activity not data Flow. Do you have any solution ?

Comment: @okr -- In copy activity try to find out an option called detect datatypes and set it to false else it will consider as Integer and will truncate 0.

Comment: @amitagarwal yes I have found it, thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that you can change the projection mapping using the "Script Editor"
So you can keep your "projection" by importing, during a debug session, the sample you are using.
Once your projection is done you can edit the "Script" to change the type of your tag
[Select the Script Editor button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McuYH.png)

You should have a script that look like that :

```
source(output(
    note as (to as string, from as string, heading as string, body as string, number as integer)
),
allowSchemaDrift: true,
validateSchema: false,
limit: 100,
ignoreNoFilesFound: false,
rowUrlColumn: 'fileName',
validationMode: 'none',
namespaces: true) ~> XmlFiles
```

You can change the type of your tag "number" to string type

```
source(output(
    note as (to as string, from as string, heading as string, body as string, number as string)
),
allowSchemaDrift: true,
validateSchema: false,
limit: 100,
ignoreNoFilesFound: false,
rowUrlColumn: 'fileName',
validationMode: 'none',
namespaces: true) ~> XmlFiles
```